# Obtain a centered "verbose equation"

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

Suppose that in the middle of the text I want to obtain a formula like the following one:
[image]
It should be centered like the equation environment. Inside the brackets I have a text and some inline equations.

Which is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the content using a `tabular` with a fixed-width `p`aragraph column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\[
  * = \left\{
    % Adjust spacing around tabular, if needed.
    %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}% ...default is 6pt
    \begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
      Here is some ordinary text with inline mathematics $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and
      then some more text that might span multiple lines \ldots
    \end{tabular}
  \right\}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can also adjust the gap between the `tabular` and the surrounding braces if needed.